# Running Multiple Spark Sessions with Different Configurations within Same Glue Job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a PySpark code running in a Glue job. The job takes an argument called 'update_mode'. I want to set different configuration for spark depending on the update_mode is full_overwrite vs upsert. Specifically, I want to switch this spark config `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode` between static vs dynamic.
I tried creating two spark sessions and using the respective spark object but it doesn't behave as expected. The other option I can think of is just creating two separate jobs with different configurations.

Any other ideas to do it in the same job?

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with Glue, so not sure how you're submitting your jobs. But [as described here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration), you can configure properties per job using `--conf spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode=...` on CLI.

> In some cases, you may want to avoid hard-coding certain configurations in a SparkConf. For instance, Spark allows you to simply create an empty conf and set spark/spark hadoop/spark hive properties.
>
> ```scala
> val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.hadoop.abc.def", "xyz")
> val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
> ```
>
> Also, you can modify or add configurations at runtime:
>
> ```
> ./bin/spark-submit \
>      --name "My app" \ 
>      --master local[4] \  
>      --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false \ 
>      --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" \ 
>      --conf spark.hadoop.abc.def=xyz \
>      --conf spark.hive.abc=xyz
>      myApp.jar
> ```

Or more dynamically from code [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75751442/496289). Your code in turn can read it from anywhere you choose to.